# Fire Javascript Function on all visible images in jCarousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcarousel

I have a jQuery tooltip plugin that displays a tooltip when I hover over a anchor tag.

I have modified my jCarousel so that my images are contained in anchor tags. When I hover over the first batch of images the tooltip hover function gets called. However, when the next batch of images come into view, the tooltip function does not get called again.

I have created a basic example of my issue here: http://jsfiddle.net/QAFZX/3/

I have tried using the itemVisibleInCallback callback but that doesn't allow my function to fire on all visible images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this issue by using a different javascript tooltip. So that on mouseover and mouseout elements on my image would either show or hide the tooltip.

Answer (score 2):

You made a function that requires a parameter, and when you called the function, you didn't bring the parameter!

```
itemLastInCallback: {
    onAfterAnimation: afterAnimationLastInCallback($(this))
}
```

instead of:

```
itemLastInCallback: {
    onAfterAnimation: afterAnimationLastInCallback
}
```

Fixed it for you, [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/QAFZX/6/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried to add your code changes to my development example which is using jCarousel loading dynamically via Javascript. Apologies I thought your code will run exactly the same.

But I am experiencing issues even with your code modifications. Here is my updated code: http://jsfiddle.net/QAFZX/11/ that matches my development environment. As you can see, afterAnimationLastInCallback is doing some other things causing the jCarousel not to work at all when I changed the callback to afterAnimationLastInCallback($(this)).